# undefined method `authenticates_with_sorcery!' for User:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, sorcery

ok I'm using sorcery gem for the log in of the main engine.
 And I want to use it also in the main engine but whenever I call the user model in the
 mountable engine it says

```
undefined method `authenticates_with_sorcery!' for User:Class
```

When I said call it's like

```
@user = User.new
```

By the way I'm using mongoid 4.0.0 and rails 4.1

Comment: Add your model, doesn't seem to be including the sorcery gem by default. Did you run the full steps for the installation?

Comment: yes. I run the rails g install:sorcery in the main engine . But still not working. Well I tried to use it also in the main engine but it's showing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issues using MongoMapper. Try making sure that `authenticates_with_sorcery!` appears beneath any of your database-related includes. For example:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  authenticates_with_sorcery!


end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the gems order in the gemfile was apparently wrong

Not good

```
gem 'sorcery'
gem 'mongoid'
```

Works!

```
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'sorcery'
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember when I posted this question sorcery gem doesn't support Mongoid 4 yet so they make a new branch in the github so that for those who are using Mongoid in that time can use sorcery with mongoid 4. Well basically the solution works for me is that I need to reference that branch in my Gemfile. I don't know right now if they already publish the latest sorcery gem.